# GitPython create local branch from remote branch

Tags: git, branch, local, gitpython

I have multiple lab machines and I need to make a copy of my remote branch on my local lab machine.  I believe the git bash command for this is:

git checkout -b mybranch origin/mybranch

How do I do the equivalent in GitPython?

I may make changes and push the changes back to origin/mybranch and then pull the changes back on to other lab machines.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look at [their docs](http://packages.python.org/GitPython/0.3.1/tutorial.html#using-git-directly), it looks like you should be able to do `git.checkout('origin/mybranch', b='mybranch')`. I'm not very familiar with GitPython though, so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: Yes I saw that.  I couldn't get it to work.  In the following example I know that the 'staging' branch exists on the remote repo.
>>? from git import *
>>? repo = Repo(r'C:\Projects\TestRepo4')
>>? git = repo.git
>>? git.checkout('origin/staging', b='staging')
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>? git.checkout('remotes/origin/staging', b='staging')
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: What version of GitPython are you using?

Comment: Does doing `repo.remotes.origin.fetch()` prior to attempting the checkout have any effect?

Comment: Solved the problem.  The windows git installer must not add "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin" to the path.